# Oracle MERGE and java prepared statement

Tags: oracle, merge

I have the below code whose sql script works perfectly on sql developer but when used in java code i.e

```
String MergeSQLMapping = "MERGE INTO test.test_table USING dual ON (CLN_POL_CODE = 22222) "
                + "WHEN MATCHED THEN "
                + "UPDATE SET  COMPANY_NAME = 'kevin', POL_ID = '22222', MAPPED_BY = '22222' "
                + "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (COMPANY_NAME, POL_ID, CLN_POL_CODE, MAPPED_BY) "
                + "VALUES ('kevin', '22222', '22222', 'workerservice'); ";
        System.out.println(MergeSQLMapping);
        dbMergeConnection = DBConnection.getStagingConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = dbMergeConnection.prepareStatement(MergeSQLMapping);
            ps.execute();
            dbMergeConnection.commit();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {       
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        } finally {
        }
```

i get the following error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any help accorded will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the string in Java.

Comment: thanx..... anyone using the above code make sure to add `dbMergeConnection.setAutoCommit(false);` else you will get `Could not commit with auto-commit set on`